# Regex Microsoft Word without destroying document formatting

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

It's well known that word's find and replace "wildcards" features suffer some severe limitations.

The following code implements true regex find and replace in a word document, and variations on it are found in other Stackoverflow and SuperUser questions.

```
Sub RegEx_PlainText(Before As String, After As String)

    Dim regexp As Object
    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")            

    With regexp
        .Pattern = Before
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True

         'could be any Range , .Range.Text , or selection object
         ActiveDocument.Range = .Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, After)

    End With
End Sub
```

However, this wipes the document of all formatting.

Word will not preserve formatting character by character even if the strings are of the same length or indeed the same string, so `ActiveDocument.Range = ActiveDocument.Range` or `Selection.Text=Selection.Text` will wipe all formatting (or more accurately, format the whole range the same as the first character in the range, and add a carriage return).  Upon reflection, this behavior isn't so surprising.

**To solve this, the following code runs a regex find, then loops through the matches and runs `.replace` only on the range where the match is found.**  This then, would only lose formatting if the match iself had a variety of formatting (for example an italicised word would be lost)

Hopefully the code comments make this quite transparent.

```
Sub RegEx(Before As String, After As String, _
          Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
          Optional Location As Range = Nothing, _
          Optional DebugMode As Boolean = False)

    'can't declare activedocument.range in parameters
    If Location Is Nothing Then Set Location = ActiveDocument.Range

    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim Foundmatches As Object
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim MatchRange As Range
    Dim offset As Integer: offset = 0
    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

   With regexp
        .Pattern = Before
        .IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive
        .Global = True

        'set foundmatches to collection of all regex matches
        Set Foundmatches = .Execute(Location.text)

        For Each Match In Foundmatches

            'set matchrange to location of found string in source doc.
            'offset accounts for change in length of  document from already completed replacements
            Set MatchRange = Location.Document _
                   .Range(Match.FirstIndex + offset, _
                          Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length + offset)

            'debugging
            If DebugMode Then
                    Debug.Print "strfound      = " & Match.Value
                    Debug.Print "matchpoint    = " & Match.FirstIndex
                    Debug.Print "origstrlength = " & Match.Length
                    Debug.Print "offset        = " & offset
                    Debug.Print "matchrange    = " & MatchRange.text
                    MatchRange.Select
                Stop

            Else
            'REAL LIFE
                'run the regex replace just on the range containing the regex match
                MatchRange = .Replace(MatchRange, After)

                'increment offset to account for change in length of document
                offset = offset + MatchRange.End - MatchRange.Start - Match.Length
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**This works on simple documents, but when I run it on a real document, `matchrange` ends up being at some point near the where the match was found, but not exactly right.**  It's not predictably off, sometimes it is to the right, and sometimes to the left. Generally the more complex the document. (links, tables of context, formatting etc.) the more wrong it ends up being.

**Does anyone know why this doesn't work, and how to fix it?**  If I could understand why this isn't working, then I might be able to determine whether this approach can be fixed, or if I just need to try a different method.

**Code includes DebugMode param which means it will just loop through the doc and highlight all matches, performing no changes.**  Also outputs a bunch of stuff to the console.  This should be helpful for anyone kind enough to tackle this problem with me.

https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx Here is a sample document (not produced by me) which may be useful.

Comment: the question you are asking is not clear....

Comment: well the question is how do I do a regex search in word without destroying the formatting.  The rest is just the code to how far I have got so far, and why it doesn't worl

Comment: Very interesting question

Comment: Two things to consider here: a) why use vbscript regex in Word VBA when Word Find methog accepts regexes (albeit occasionally slightly different to "normal" regex), and b) replacing words changes the range of course! What I would do is a) use Word's Find method and b) consider starting from the end of the document upwards so as to preserve range values.

Comment: @LocEngineer Don't want this thread to turn into a long discussion as to exactly what the limitations and drawbacks of word's "regex" are vs. real regex, but happy to discuss it in Chat. Suffice to say word's regex won't do for various purposes.

Comment: @LocEngineer as for point b) I already accounted for this (although working backwards would have made more sense than my offset variable). I've updated the question so that that's a little clearer.

Comment: I think you should provide example when it is not workin as for simple text solution looks ok. Have you considered all hidden document marks, like paragraphs end, table row/cell end, soft space, etc...?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Included sample document link in question now. I agree with you that things like tables, links, contents pages etc. are the problem. The find-text-return-index & go-to-index parts of the code seem to handle these in different ways. Imho fixing on a case by case basis is bound to keep running into new exceptions and end up v. long and unwieldy, and ultimately still imperfect so I don't think it's the right approach. Problem isn't whether these chars are counted or not, it's that they are accounted for differently by the method which returns the index & the one which goes to it.

Comment: Using index values for characters is simply not reliable and cannot be made reliable - it's the nature of the beast. Best recommendation I can make would be to compare the actual string with the index location's Text. If it doesn't match, try "walking" the start and end points until it does...

Comment: @CindyMeister I started doing that but it got to the point it was having to walk in both directions (sometimes for a very long distance) from the "found" point, for some documents the next match being closer than the targeted match, and so missing some matches altogether.  The way I solved it in the end was to just take the text of the found string, apply the regex on that string, then get the output and then pipe the found string and the regex'd string into word's native find and replace. I'll tidy it up and post the solution over the next couple of days. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this for, well, years now myself. Word's built-in "regular expressions" (wildcards in Advanced Find) aren't up to the task without accounting for all possibilities, which can be...I'll leave it at "daunting". Things that throw it off: hidden text, tables of contents, fields (of any kind), tables, drawings (not images, but other drawings done in Word). I suspect embedded objects would also cause issues, but haven't tried that. I'll definitely have to try the kludge mentioned here, though! Might solve my immediate issue!

Answer (score 4):

@Some_Guy: thanks for asking this question, I had a similar problem and your post saved me quite a bit of time.

This is the kludge I came up with:

```
Sub RegEx(Before As String, After As String, _
          Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
          Optional Location As Range = Nothing, _
          Optional DebugMode As Boolean = False)

    'can't declare activedocument.range in parameters
    If Location Is Nothing Then Set Location = ActiveDocument.Range

    Dim j As Long
    Dim regexp As Object
    Dim Foundmatches As Object
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim MatchRange As Range
    Dim offset As Integer: offset = 0
    Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regexp
        .Pattern = Before
        .IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive
        .Global = True

        'set foundmatches to collection of all regex matches
        Set Foundmatches = .Execute(Location.Text)
        For j = Foundmatches.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            If DebugMode = True Then
                'debugging
                Debug.Print Foundmatches(j), .Replace(Foundmatches(j), After)
            Else
                'REAL LIFE

                'run a plain old find/replace on the found string and eplace strings
                With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
                    .Text = Foundmatches(j)
                    .Replacement.Text = regexp.Replace(Foundmatches(j), After)
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Basically I use a simple find/replace with strings that match each item found (and would be replaced) with a regex, would decent support for it exist in Word). Note that any text replaced takes on the formatting of the first replaced character, so if the first word is in bold, then all the replaced text will be bold.

Comment: It's been a long time since I came up with this so my head's out of it.  I did also come up with a kludge that worked in the end (which I always planned to neaten up and post here some time).  I'll have a look at this and my old code (on a backup somewhere) some time this week and see if I have anything to add, but I think I actually may have done exactly what you did, used word's native find and replace on the string regex finds.

Comment: Functioning, thanks. Just to add that usually we need a `.Multiline = True` on object regexp initialization